# How to run android gcm sample on api 22?

Tags: android, api, gradle, sdk

I want to run GCM sample application in android studio, but google recently update it's API to 23. My problem is I have API 22 and I can't download API 23 from google in android sdk manager because of sanctions.
can anyone guide me how to downgrade api to 22.
I get this error from gradle:

> Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\Bartar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   Open Android SDK Manager

I clone google GCM sample from this page:[Try Cloud Messaging for Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

Answer (score 1):

For updating SDK manager to API 23,

> I think it may caused by you don't have 23 API, Go to Tools > Android
>   SDK Manager and check to see if API-23 is installed.

Here is the complete tutorial which works on Api 22 related with GCM,

http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139